# How to verify that a shredding has been done?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, shred

I want to test a magnetic disk to be (quite) sure a shredding has been done.

- Hypo1 : a `shred -n 3` was applyed
- Hypo2 : a `shred -n 1` was applyed
- Hypo3 : no shred was applyed

How to test in which state the disk is?

Comment: What kind of disk is it? Flash memory & SSD's don't always keep data in the same place, and they can "hide" sectors in normally inaccessible areas, so truly erasing all data could be impossible (unless you use Mjölnir). Anyway, did you copy a few sectors/files before shredding, then compare them after shredding?

Comment: Hi @Wen2050 . My subject is about magnetic disks, I will edit my qst. I knew flash based storage have strange behaviour making erasing complicated. (sadly, my best source of info is this hacker book in French https://guide.boum.org/tomes/1_hors_connexions/unepage/#index77h3 )

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference between shred -1 and -3 in a practical sense. You're just running more than one pass of the wipe

A 'simple' way to check if a disk has been properly wiped is to try recovery with common data recovery or forensic tools to see if any data is there. I'd go with testdisk since it's pretty common but feel free to throw whatever you want at it

Comment: There is a difference between shred 1 and shred 3, but that was not the important point of my question. Thank you for your answer.
When the computer rewrites 1 over 0, it gives 0.95 instead and when rewriting 1 over 1, it gives rather 1.0555... (Source https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html)

Comment: ...imo. not really. You just run more passes and feel more smug about it. The guttman paper was written with much older drives with bigger domains

Comment: @Sandburg The only different thing is the algorithm used for the wipe. In theory you can reconstruct data given that you also know the algorithm. But you just can't differentiate beteween shred 1 and shred n. That's like erasing a file_a, then filling the space with more files, then delete everything and try to recover file_a. As said by Journeyman Geek, you can check the data with tools like "R-studio", it can take a long time, and see if you can recover any.